# How to solve MAB by linear program?

Tags: linear-programming, reinforcement-learning

To solve multi-armed bandit problem, the common approaches are UCB or TS and there are many variants of these algorithms. I am wondering if it is possible to model and solve this problem as a linear program? If yes, is it possible to derive regret bound for the algorithm?
I have seen some papers that use LP, primal-dual to solve bandit with knapsack constraint, but I don't know how in general it is possible to implement this approach for general bandit problems. I would be thankful if you explain it or provide some references.